# How can i get sum of squared errors(SSE) from k means algorithm?

Tags: r

I Have a data frame with two columns and 450 rows. First I have to run a K-means algorithm with different k values(meaning k clusters). And for each time I run a different k value I have to calculate the SSE. I have just the mathematical equation given. SSE is calculated by squaring  each points distance to its respective clusters centroid and then summing everything up. So at the end I should have SSE for each k value.

I have gotten to the place where you run the k means algorithm:

```
Data.kemans <- kmeans(data, centers = 3)
```

How could I get the SSE (sum of squared errors) from this `data.kmeans` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using scikit-learn to calculate the SSE value, then there is a built-in attribute .inertia_ for that.

```
from sklearn. cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans()
kmeans.fit(your_data)
kmeans.inertia_ #returns the SSE value
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.

Comment: A code-only answer is a low-quality answer. Add some explanation as to why you think this code-snippet would work.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24110728).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is returned by `kmeans`. The documentation says:

Value

kmeans returns an object of class "kmeans" which has a print and a fitted method. It is a list with at least the following components:

(...)

totss
The total sum of squares.

withinss
Vector of within-cluster sum of squares, one component per cluster.

tot.withinss
Total within-cluster sum of squares, i.e. sum(withinss).

betweenss
The between-cluster sum of squares, i.e. totss-tot.withinss.

Hence, `Data.kmeans$withinss` should give you the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered the same thing. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```r
# kmeans clustering on R's (built in) iris dataset
cl <- kmeans(iris[,c(1:4)], centers = 3)

# Sum of squared errors for each cluster
cl$withinss
# [1]   6.432121  17.669524 118.651875

# Total sum of squared errors across all clusters
cl$tot.withinss
# [1] 142.7535
```